# How to use SSH key to deploy angular production build to an external server using bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: angular, bitbucket-pipelines

We are trying to use Bitbucket Pipelines to deploy a basic angular application to a VM on Google Cloud but are not sure how to use SSH key to connect to the server to copy the build files. Looking for examples but could not find.

We were able to do the same manually using Putty/SSH commands to copy the **dist** files.

We have the public/private key from Google Cloud's VM, and added them to Bitbucket Pipelines > SSH Keys

[image]

Our YML script is as below:

```
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
       caches:
         - node
       script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
         - npm install
         - npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.4
         - ng build --prod
         - cd dist/
         - ssh -i ???
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris stated, [that article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html) is the right starting point.
Steps are:

1. *Add SSH key in BitBucket*, either via the UI, or by running 
   `ssh-keygen`
2. *Update the known hosts* via UI.
3. *Add the public key to a remote host* via

   `cat ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key.pub | ssh username@remote_host "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod -R go= ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

or via

```
`ssh-copy-id -i my_ssh_key username@remote_host`
```

4. Then copy the files with this command (which should be in your script):

   `scp username@remote_host:/path/to/file /path/to/destination`

Comment: On bitbucket pipeline, we need to use a public key given to us that is generated on the remote host. Updated my question with the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure [this tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html) might come in handy

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this as below:

1. Under Bitbucket > Project source repository > Settings > Pipelines > SSH Keys

   - Add private and public keys and
   - Add Known hosts (this will the IP address of the server you want to push the code to. In our case this is a VM on Google Cloud)
2. Update your script as below:

   ```
   image: node:8
   pipelines: 
   default: 
     - step: 
        caches: 
          - node 
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository. 
          #- echo "$(ls -la)" 
          - npm install 
          - npm install -g @angular/cli 
          - ng build --prod 
          - echo "$(ls -la dist/)" 
          - scp -r dist/ user@1.2.3.4:/home/suren/temp
   ```